# iOS in app/push messages by GameCenter ID

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, game-center

Can I send an in-app message (or a push notification) to players who reach certain achievements or are in a leaderboard in GameCenter?
Is there an ID associated with the GameCenter that I can use to contact this user in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game Center doesn't let you send them specific messages. You'd have to use push notifications and keep track (on your server-side) for which users achieved the achievement you're interested in, as well as what their push notification ID is.

Comment: so you mean, I need to track with my app, I can't track through gamecenter?